# Detect the name of required field and not validated when submit a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, form-submit

I create a form in html5 like this example :

```
<form action="/my/url/insert.php" method="POST">
     <div class="row"> 
          name <input name="name" required/> 
     </div>
     <div class="row"> 
          type <input name="type" required/> 
     </div>
     <div class="row"> 
          year <input name="year" required/> 
     </div>

     ....

     <div class="row"> 
          album <input name="album" required/> 
     </div>
     <div class="row"> 
          <input type="submit" value="Save"/>
     </div>
</form>


<script>
    $('form').submit(function(){
         console.log('test');
    });
</script>
```

## The problem :

I want to detect the name of the required field that are not validated when submiting and logging  it.

for example : if I don't fill the input "album" when submit i detect it before the message "a field is required..."

is there a way to do this ?

thank you.

Comment: Use `:required` selector

Comment: Which required field? You have several.

Comment: @Utkanos:only the inputs that are not validated

Comment: If you don't want to form validate, use `novalidate` attribute in your `form`.

Comment: If there are any not validated inputs, the `submit` will never be triggered. So your question is useless. Give us some example where you want to use it. Otherwise loop all inputs an look witch are not empty.

Comment: @eisbehr: you are right, sadly, i just tested an example to check the empty input for each required field. but the submit is not triggered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you go.. Loop through each `input:required` field and get its name with `.attr`.

```js
$('form').submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).find('input:required').each(function(){
    console.log($(this).attr('name'));  
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="/my/url/insert.php" method="POST">
  <div class="row">
    name
    <input name="name" required/>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    type
    <input name="type" required/>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    year
    <input name="year" required/>
  </div>

  ....

  <div class="row">
    album
    <input name="album" required/>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
  </div>
</form>
```

---

**Updated**

```js
$('form').submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).find('input:required').each(function(){
    if($(this).val()==""){ //check if its empty
      console.log($(this).attr('name'));  
    }
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form novalidate action="/my/url/insert.php" method="POST">
  <div class="row">
    name
    <input name="name" required/>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    type
    <input name="type" required/>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    year
    <input name="year" required/>
  </div>

  ....

  <div class="row">
    album
    <input name="album" required/>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
  </div>
</form>
```

Assuming that only required will be the property for validation, above condition will hold good and yea, by default when you say required, browser will have its validation suppressing validation written by you. If you want your validation to work, add `novalidate` to `form` as said in one of the comments above..

Comment: thanks for your answer. but i search only the inputs that are not validated

Comment: Git the inner selector a context, to prevent getting elemets outside the form. `$('input:required', $(this))` or `$(this).find('input:required')`.

Comment: @GuruprasadRao : I tested it, but the submit is never called untill i fill all the required inputs.

Answer (score 3):

Select them by property `required`:

```
$(function() {
    $('form').submit(function(){
        $("input:required", $(this)).each(function() {
            console.log($(this).attr("name"));
        });
    });
});
```

To do a simple required check on your own make a simple "not empty" condition. But for this, your form need the `novalidate` class, otherwise `submit` callback will not be triggered and nothing ever happens.

```
$(function() {
    $('form').submit(function(){
        $("input:required", $(this)).each(function() {
            if( $(this).val() != "" )
                console.log($(this).attr("name"));
        });
    });
});
```

Full example here: https://jsfiddle.net/vvdh66rb/

Answer (score 1):

You can also do like this:

```
<form action="/my/url/insert.php" method="POST" onSubmit="return myFunction()">
 <div class="row"> 
      <!--I am only giving id to one to show an exmaple you can give to differnt-->
      name <input name="name" id="some" required/> 
 </div>
 <div class="row"> 
      type <input name="type" required/> 
 </div>
 <div class="row"> 
      year <input name="year" required/> 
 </div>

 ....

 <div class="row"> 
      album <input name="album" required/> 
 </div>
 <div class="row"> 
      <input type="submit" value="Save"/>
 </div>
</form>
<script>
 function myFunction() {
 var x = document.getElementById('some').value;
   if (x == "" || x == null) {
   alert('sadsd');
   return false;
   //You can give anything else than alert
   }
 }
```